# BLE GATT server data format

Tags: qt, bluetooth, format, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt

I'm playing on this example:

https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-dev/qtbluetooth-heartrate-server-example.html

to better understand how to configure a GATT server.
The example fakes a HeartRate profile. In detail it creates a characteristic with this client descriptor:

```
const QLowEnergyDescriptorData clientConfig(QBluetoothUuid::ClientCharacteristicConfiguration, QByteArray(2, 0));
```

from here:

https://developer.bluetooth.org/gatt/descriptors/Pages/DescriptorViewer.aspx?u=org.bluetooth.descriptor.gatt.client_characteristic_configuration.xml

I understand it has both notifications and indications disabled by default (in fact I need to enable them from a client application in order to be notified).

What I really don't understand is this code:

```
quint8 currentHeartRate = 60;
const auto heartbeatProvider = [&service, &currentHeartRate, &valueChange]() {
    QByteArray value;
    value.append(char(0)); // Flags that specify the format of the value.
    value.append(char(currentHeartRate)); // Actual value.
    QLowEnergyCharacteristic characteristic = service->characteristic(QBluetoothUuid::HeartRateMeasurement);
    service->writeCharacteristic(characteristic, value); // Potentially causes notification.
    ...
```

Well, it appends two bytes to the characteristic's value because it was defined above:

```
QLowEnergyCharacteristicData charData;
charData.setUuid(QBluetoothUuid::HeartRateMeasurement);
charData.setValue(QByteArray(2, 0));
```

but what does the first one mean?

```
value.append(char(0)); // Flags that specify the format of the value.
```

I cannot find any documentation about this "format".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first byte is the flags field specified in the Heart Rate Service (HRS)[here](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/adopted-specifications). In this example, flags field indicates that the heart rate measurement value is in uint8 format.

Comment: I generated random UUID to make my own GATT server. But if I try to set both values and descriptors as `QByteArray(1, 0)` in order to have the payload only one byte length I get: `qt.bluetooth.bluez: attribute of type "{00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb}" has invalid length of 1 bytes`. The same happens for any numbers of bytes but 2. Why? Now there is nothing about heartrate profile!

Comment: 00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb is the Client characteristic configuration descriptor uuid, who's value is 2 bytes. It appears you are setting this descriptor value.